# To $_GET or not to $_GET

Tags: php, post, get

```
<?php
/*random1 is a randomly generated number*/
if($_GET){
 /*picking 'i' using $_GET and doing a query in mysql*/
 /*Unable to pick the value from select box, using either $_GET or $_POST*/
 }
else{
  /*some other query*/
}
?>
  <a href="?i=<?php echo $random1;?>"> <span> Roll the dice!</span></a>

<span>Categories:&nbsp;</span> 
<select name="cat_area" >
<option value="all">All</option>
<option value="all">One</option>
<option value="all">Two</option>
<option value="all">three</option>
</select>
```

My problem is: When I click *roll the dice*, it knows the value of `i` but how to send the value of one of the 'options' from the select box along with the `i`.  I am a newbie in php. Tell me if I am going wrong in using wrong kind of input for this.

Comment: I could have used a form..but my problem is, i want the url to be different every time i click that

Comment: oopss. sorry...ignore those values.. i was just trying to ask how to do this ..generally

Comment: @RobbieDc Why do you want the URL to be different?

Comment: This question makes no sense, are you even wrapping you `<select>` within a form?

Comment: Dave.. so that I can bookmark a page with certain value for i

Comment: Robbie, you have to ask a sensible question. Not some sketch of whatever abstract picture of something imaginary. Voting to close.

Comment: guess..i messed it all up..sorry guys..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you currently have the same `value` for each option, so you won't be able to tell which they selected anyway.

```
<select name="cat_area" >
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

You will also want to add the random `i` as a hidden field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $random1;?>" />
```

Are you happy with how to create forms?

If you specifically want it to be an `<a` link then you're going to need a `onChange` type Javascript function on the select to modify the link. Does it need to be a link?

Comment: yeah..it needs to be a link..  i want different url to be displayed everytime i click the roll

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if($_GET)
{
  echo $_GET['i']; 
  echo $_GET['cat_area'];
}
?>

<a href="?i=<?php echo $random1;?>"> <span> Roll the dice!</span></a>

<span>Categories:&nbsp;</span> 
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $random1;?>" />
  <select name="cat_area" >
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="value_1">One</option>
    <option value="value_2">Two</option>
    <option value="value_3">three</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

EDIT

after some confessions made in the comments I can guess the answer. Still not sure though.

1) Make a form like this

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?=$random1?>">
  <span>Categories:&nbsp;</span> 
  <select name="cat_area" >
    <option>All</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

2) Click a button.

3) Watch the address bar. Bookmark it.

<s>I see no point in sending a *random* value back and forth.

As for your combo box - just put it in the form
And, as Alex pointed out, you have to have different values. Or just use the value between tags.</s>

```
<?php
if($_GET){
  $random1=rand();
  $cat_area=$_GET['cat_area'];
  // do your query
}
?>

<form>
  <span>Categories:&nbsp;</span> 
  <select name="cat_area" >
    <option>All</option>
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
</form>
```